# Itext 7 using material ui icons in pdf

Tags: java, itext, itext7, google-material-icons

How do I use material ui icons as font while creating a PDF document. I am trying to use [MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) as the font.

Is there any example I can refer to. or is there a better way of handling font icons in PDF docs using itext7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking but it should go like this:

```
PdfFont f1 = PdfFontFactory.createFont("MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Testing of symbols \ue000,\ue0bb").setFont(f1);
```

Note that the characters are in the private area. Install the font in windows and use the character map application to locate the charactres.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I was doing the same thing with the font. But looks like I was using the unicode chars wrong.

Comment: @AnirudhKaranam If you're happy with the answer please mark it as correct, thank you.